# Does Monty Hall Problem have any effect on an equation with multiple choices?

Tags: probability, monty-hall

I am having a discussion with someone that insists the Monty Hall Problem would improve the probability of guessing the correct door. However, the circumstances are different.

You have four doors. Only one has the right answer. We are not concerned about the probability of guessing the correct answer on the first try, but whether or not using Monty Hall Problem will improve your chances on guessing the correct door earlier. You choose one door. It's wrong. You choose again until you get the correct door. Does using the Monty Hall Problem better your chances of guessing the correct door with less guesses?

My argument is that since there are multiple choices, the Monty Hall Problem probability factor doesn't apply. The equation is reset each time you choose a new door, so the base probability factor is simply evenly split amongst the remaining doors.

The other person's argument is following a 4 door Monty Hall Problem that only has 1 door opened. You choose Door 1, you open Door 2. Find out that Door 2 is wrong. (S)he says there is now a 25% chance it is Door 1, and a 37.5% chance it is Door 3 and a 37.5% chance it is Door 4.

Who is right? I'm not sure if I'm overlooking something. I don't believe I am though.

If I am right, how would I thoroughly explain how the Monty Hall Problem doesn't apply here? I've tried explaining it how I have here to no avail and the other person still believes they're right.

Comment: The Monty Hall problem doesn't "do" anything.  The probability is whatever it is...
But what do you mean by "the equation is reset"?
Please explain exactly what are the assumptions in this problem.

Comment: I simply mean that after you choose for the first time, if it's wrong, you choose again. The logic you would use regarding the Monty Hall Problem would start from the beginning again before it gets to the end to provide any useful statistics.

Comment: "I simply mean that after you choose for the first time, if it's wrong, you choose again. "  That's not in any way resembling the monty hall problem.  That's just guessing untill you guess it.  Your chances are 100% of guessing the car eventually.

Comment: So to clarify, you can't use the Monty Hall Problem to better your chances of choosing the right door on your second or third guess?

Comment: "The other person's argument is following a 4 door Monty Hall Problem that only has 1 door opened. You choose Door 1, you open Door 2. Find out that Door 2 is wrong."  ... Except 1 in 4 cases you will open door 2 and it will be right.

Comment: All you know after opening some doors and not finding the car is that the car is behind one of the unopened doors.  You have no reason to think that any one of those unopened doors is better than any other one.  The fact that you "chose" one of them is irrelevant.

Comment: You can't use the Monty Hall Problem unless you have Monty Hall.  Someone has to know what is going on and assure that you only see *wrong* choices.

Comment: the whole *POINT* of Monty Hall is that Monty Hall is there thinking.  "There will always be a wrong choice; it is my job to *always*  show it".  Without that person you will not always see a wrong choice you will on a regular probability see a right choice randomly.  In having a host *conciously* show a wrong choice he is skewing the results.  Without a host the choices are not being skewed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the Monty Hall problem you need Monty Hall.  Without him you have this.

You pick Door 1 and open Door 2.

1 out of 4 times the car will be in door 1 and Door 2 is a goat.

1 out of 4 times the car will be in door 2 and you see the car.

1 out of 4 times door 1 and door 2 will be wrong and the car is behind door 3.

1 out of 4 times door 1 and door 2 will be wrong and the car is behind door 3.

You are assuming the second case just didn't happen.  So given the *condition* that it didn't happen you have 3 equally likely scenarios.

The car was behind door 1

The car was behind door 3

The car was behind door 4

> You are right.

But if you *had* a monty hall then what would happen is

The door you choose is called A and the door monty shows you is B. The other two are C and D.

1 in 4 the car is behind A.

3 in 4 the car is not.  3 in 8 the car is behind C.  ANd 3 in 8 the car is behing D.

> Your friend is right.
>
> **But this is only if you have a host**.

If you don't:

1 in 4 it is behind A.

**1 in 4 it is actually behind B and you SEE it (that never happens with the host)**

1 in 4 is is behind C.

and 1 in 4 it is behind D.

==== if you actually do the Monty Hall problem====

1 out of 4 cases you choose the right door the first time.

Monty shows you a goat.  There are 3 doors left.  The one you choose with a care and two with a goat.  You switch to a goat.

There are 3 doors left.  The one you first chose with the car, the one you now chose with a goat, and another with a goat.  Monty shows you that one with a goat.

There are 2 doors left.  The one you first chose with a car.  And the one you currently chose the one with a goat.  You switch and choose the car.

1 out of 4 times this will happen.

3 out of 4 times you will choose a door with a goat.

There will be 3 doors you didn't pick one with a car and two with goats.  Monty will show you a door with a goat.  There are three doors remaining. The door you currently picked with a goat; a door you didn't pick with a car; a door you didn't pick with a goat.  You switch.

A) 3 out of 8 times you will switch to the door with a car.  B) 3 out of 8 times you will switch to the door with a goat.

A) There are three doors.  The one you picked with the car, and two you didn't pick with a goat.  Monty shows you one of the goats and you switch to the other goat.  There are two unopened doors.  You have picked the one with the goat.  You lose.

This happens 3 out of 8 times.

B0  There are three doors.  The one you picked with a goat.  The one you didn't pick with a car.  The one you didn't pick with a goat.  Monty shows you the one with the goat.  You switch to the car.  You win.

That happes 3 out of 8 times.

So the Monty Hall method works $5$ out of $8$ times.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand the question (or perhaps I did not elaborate enough). In this scenario, nobody reveals anything to you, but rather you open the door yourself to know that it is wrong. The door that is 'revealed' to you is not always wrong, it could be the correct answer. For instance, you 'choose' Door 1 but open Door 2 to ATTEMPT to eliminate it as a possibility. Door 2 is correct, in this case you got it in the first try. The 'swap' tactic has no validity here (regarding how I see it) because you never actually swap anything.

Comment: That is NOT the Monty Hall Problem.  That is just guessing.  This is called conditional probability.  The probability of you being correct is 1 in 4.  But GIVEN that door 2 wrong (a probability of 3 out of 4).  Then the probability of you being correct *given* door 2 is wrong is $\frac {\frac 14}{\frac 34}=\frac 13$ (because we are only considering 3/4 of the cases..

Comment: Bayes theorem is P(A|B) = $\frac {P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$.  So probability (YOU ARE RIGHT given OTHER DOOR IS WRONG = $\frac {\text{P(OTHER DOOR IS WRONG given YOU ARE RIGHT)P(YOU ARE RIGHT)}}{\text{P(OTHER DOOR IS WRONG)}} = \frac {1*\frac 14}{\frac 34} = \frac 13$.  Which is just common sense.  Each unknown door is equally likely.  One is known to be wrong.  The others are equally likely.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The Monty Hall effect only shows up when someone else knows the correct answer. In the standard Monty Hall problem, the host knows which door has the prize, and so when he chooses a door to open he gives you useful information.

Answer (score 0):

Using Bayes theorem:

Your scenario *WITHOUT* a host.

$P(\text{You pick right door}|\text{shown door is wrong}) = \frac {P(\text{shown door is wrong}|\text{You pick right door})\times P(\text{you pick right door})}{P(\text{shown door is wrong})}=$

$\frac {1\times \frac 14}{\frac 34}=\frac 13$.

So probability one of the other two doors is correct.  $1 - \frac 13 = \frac 23$.  And each is equally likely so probability a specific other door is correct is $\frac 13$

But WITH A host.  It's the host job to make sure the shown door is wrong.  Sp $P(\text{shown door is wrong}) = 1$

So

$P(\text{You pick right door}|\text{shown door is wrong}) = \frac {P(\text{shown door is wrong}|\text{You pick right door})\times P(\text{you pick right door})}{P(\text{shown door is wrong})}=$

$\frac {1\times \frac 14}{1}=\frac 14$.

So probability one of the other two doors is correct.  $1 - \frac 14 = \frac 34$.  And each is equally likely so probability a specific other door is correct is $\frac 38$

.... or ... WITHOUT a host these happen.

Car is behind door 1.  1-4 times.

**1: Car, 2:  Not Car *show*, 3: Not Car, 4: Not Car** (1 in 12)

**1: Car, 2:  Not Car , 3: Not Car*show*, 4: Not Car** (1 in 12)

**1: Car, 2:  Not Car , 3: Not Car, 4: Not Car *show*** (1 in 12)

Car is behind door 2.  1-4 times.

$\color{red}{\text{1: Not Car, 2:   Car *show*, 3: Not Car, 4: Not Car  (1 in 12)}}$

1: Not Car, 2: Car, 3: Not Car *show*, 4: Not Car (1 in 12)

1: Not Car, 2: Car, 3: Not Car , 4: Not Car *show*(1 in 12)

Car is behind door 3.  1-4 times.

1: Not Car, 2: Not Car *show*, 3: Car , 4: Not Car (1 in 12)

$\color{red}{\text{1: Not Car, 2:   Not Car , 3:  Car *show*, 4: Not Car  (1 in 12)}}$

1: Not Car, 2: Not Car, 3:  Car , 4: Not Car *show*(1 in 12)

Car is behind door 4.  1-4 times.

1: Not Car, 2: Not Car *show*, 3: Not Car , 4:  Car (1 in 12)

1: Not Car, 2: Not Car, 3:  Not Car *show* , 4: Not Car (1 in 12)

$\color{red}{\text{1: Not Car, 2:   Not Car , 3: Not  Car, 4:  Car *show*  (1 in 12)}}$

If we know the red ones didn't happen each of the others are equally likely.

And WITH a host:

Car is behind door 1.  1-4 times.

**1: Car, 2: Not car *shown*, 3: Not car, 4: Not car** (1 in 12)

**1: Car, 2: Not car , 3: Not car *shown*, 4: Not car** (1 in 12)

**1: Car, 2: Not car , 3: Not car, 4: Not car *shown*** (1 in 12)

Car is behind door 2.  1-4 times.

1: Not Car, 2: car, 3: not car *shown*, 4: not car.  (1 in 8)

1:  Not Car, 2: car, 3: not car, 4: not car *shown*. (1 in 8)

Car is behind door 3.  1-4 times.

1: Not Car, 2: not car  *shown*, 3:  car, 4: not car.  (1 in 8)

1:  Not Car, 2: not car, 3:  car, 4: not car *shown*. (1 in 8)

Car is behind door 4.  1-4 times.

1: Not Car, 2: not car  *shown*, 3:  not car, 4:  car.  (1 in 8)

1:  Not Car, 2: not car, 3:  not car *shown*, 4:  car. (1 in 8)

*WITH* a host we know that a car will never be shown and that changes everything.